# Populate select drop down list, each row is blank

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to populate my dropdown list, but it doesnt work. 
Am i missing something?
My dropdown populates, but it doesnt show database name in it, just blank on each row.

If i only use <"select data-bind="options: databases"> my dropdown fills with [object Object].

The json result my controller returns:

```
{
   "success":true,
   "databases":"[\r\n  {\r\n    \"Id\": \"1\",\r\n    \"Name\": \"Test1\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"Id\": \"2\",\r\n    \"Name\": \"Test2\"\r\n]"
}
```

Thanks on forehand!

The code:

```
 <select data-bind="options: databases, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id', value: 'Id', optionsCaption: 'Choose DB'"></select>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var data = [];

var DatabaseViewModel = function (data) {
    this.Id = data.Id;
    this.Name = data.Name;
};

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.databases = ko.observableArray(data);

    $(function () {
        // on this click event, we popular the observable array
        $('#load').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("LoadDatabases", "StoredProcedure")",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        var array = [];
                        $.each(response.databases, function (index, value) {
                            array.push(new DatabaseViewModel(value));
                        });
                        self.databases(array);
                    } else {
                        alert(response.message);
                        window.location.href = response.redirectUrl;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

LoadDatabases action  in controller:

```
   [HttpParamAction]
         [HttpPost]
           public JsonResult LoadDatabases()
          {
            try
              {
                  var dbs = _configService.GetAllDatabases().ToList();

            var databaseList = new List<DatabaseModel>();


            foreach (var db in dbs)
            {
                var model = new DatabaseModel { Id = db.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), Name = db.Name };
                databaseList.Add(model);
            }

            return Json(new
            {
                success = true,
                databases = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(databaseList),
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                success = false,
                message = string.Format("Databases not available at the moment due to {0}.      Please try reconnect to the database!", ex.Message),
                redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "DatabaseServerConnect")
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please log out the `response.databases` in your success function before the `$.each` call? My guess is the the property names used in your `DatabaseViewModel` are not matching the ones what you get from the server...

Comment: I've updated my post. Hope it's more clear now. :)

Comment: can you also post your `LoadDatabases` action code?

Comment: This line is your problem: `databases = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(databaseList),` you are double JSON serializing your `databaseList`... just write `databases = databaseList,` or in the client side you need to parse it by hand: `$.each(JSON.parse(response.databases), function (index, value) { `

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Now it works like a charm. :D If i now select an item in the dropdown i want the id to be sent to my controller. Do i need to make an ajax call for that too ?

Comment: If you want to send back data to your controller, than you need to do an ajax call or if you are have a `form` element around your select then you need to submit that. But that is now a completely different question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted JSON is looking funny because it seems it is double encoded.

But looking at your server side code clearly shows that this is your problem:

```
databases = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(databaseList),
```

So you are double JSON encoding your `databases` property because the `return Json` already does the encoding for you.

There is two way to solve this:

- get rid of the double encoding on the server side, with writing:

  ```
  return Json(new
      {
          success = true,
          databases = databaseList,
      }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  ```
- or you need to explicitly JSON.parse the `response.databases` on the client side:

  ```
  var array = [];
  $.each(JSON.parse(response.databases), function (index, value) {
      array.push(new DatabaseViewModel(value));
  });
  self.databases(array);
  ```